# Removing ads from RSS feeds?

Tags: rss

I want to publish a news website feeds on my website. However they have included annoying banner advertising next to each headline. Is it possible to remove them from the XML feeds?

Comment: it probably depends on how you publish these feeds (which treatment, via which language...). You can probably do it with php/python/java depending on your server code. Btw, you should show us the XML structure if you want us to help you.

Comment: You would need to find a news feed that allows syndication, while you could just remove the ads, you may be violating the copyright of the content in that feed.  Google News might be a better feed to use http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?answer=59255&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be easy<sup>1</sup> to parse the XML, remove the offending element from the heading, and then serialize the tree-structure back to a XML (RSS) file.

**But**, it may violate the license of the RSS file, since you'll be actively manipulating the feed.

---

<sup>1)</sup> You'll be editing the `//rss/channel/item/title` nodes.